# Finish request operation before next operation of the application

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm getting some data from my database and saving it into a object I have created (called "ManejadorMateria"). Then, I want to be able to show this data in a table view on the next view controller; the problem is that the request operation needs to be made on the prepareforsegue method of the previous view controller, and the method cellForRowAtIndexPath of the table view is called before the data I need is saved on the object ManejadorMateria.

What can I do to get that data before the method cellForRowAtIndexPath is triggered?

To make the request to the database, I'm using this code:

```
-(void)commandWithParams:(NSMutableDictionary*)params onCompletion     (JSONResponseBlock)completionBlock
{
NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
[self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                path:kAPIPath
                          parameters:params
           constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {

           }];

AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:   apiRequest];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //success!
    completionBlock(responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    //failure :(
    completionBlock([NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[error localizedDescription]   forKey:@"error"]);
}];

[operation start];
}
```

To get the data I need, I use this code:

```
- (void)cargarMateriasDeCarrera:(NSString *)carrera{

Materias = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Manejador = [[ManejadorMateria alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"getMaterias", @"command",
                               carrera, @"carrera",
                               nil];


[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params
                           onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
                               //handle the response
                               NSDictionary* res = [json objectForKey:@"result"];
                               Materia *materiafuente = [[Materia alloc]init];

                               for (id r in res) {
                                   materiafuente.Nombre = [NSString      stringWithFormat:@"%@",[r objectForKey:@"nombre"]];
                                   materiafuente.Codigo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[r objectForKey:@"codigo"]];
                                   materiafuente.Descripcion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[r objectForKey:@"descripcion"]];
                                   materiafuente.GradoDificultad = [r objectForKey:@"grado"];
                                   [Materias addObject:materiafuente];

                               }
                               [Manejador setMasterMateriasTodas:Materias];

                                }];


}
```

and finally on the prepareforsegue on that same view controller I have:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

usuario.Carrera = [carreras objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
TablaMateriasViewController3 *tbvc3 = [segue destinationViewController];
tbvc3.usuario = usuario;


NSString *command = @"registraCarrera";
NSMutableDictionary *params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              command, @"command",
                              usuario.Carnet, @"carnet",
                              usuario.Carrera, @"carrera",
                              nil];

[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params
                           onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
                           }];
[self cargarMateriasDeCarrera:usuario.Carrera];
tbvc3.Manejador = Manejador;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can i do to get that data before the method cellForRowAtIndexPath is triggered.

iOS is event-driven. You can't rely on the order of things. You do not know when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be called. So, when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called, either you have the data or you don't. If you don't, then you supply a filler, or nothing at all. If you do, then you supply the data.

If you know that you have the data and you want `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be called *again*, then call `reloadData` or one of the related `reload...` methods (such as `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`). For example, you could call that in your completion method when you've obtained the data for a row.

In my book, I give an example where the image for every row of a cell has to be downloaded. At first, every image is missing. But when the table view asks for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and the image is missing, we start to download that image. When it arrives, we refresh that row, and so `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called again and now we *do* have the image, so we supply the image and it appears in the table:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch37.html#_http_requests

Complete downloadable example project:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/ch37p920downloader/p754p772downloader

You can probably adapt that same strategy.

Comment: i was expecting something with Threads instead of recalling that method because i dont know exactly the size of the data i am getting

Comment: When you download asynchronously (as you are doing) you *are* using threads.

Comment: thanks matt, but then how can i put to sleep the main thread while the operation waits for completion

Comment: You don't. Read what I said in my answer. Look at the discussion in my book. When the operation does complete, you reload the table row(s) - on the main thread, of course.

Comment: thanks @matt, it worked using [self.tableview reloadData];